# Adding featured for post using database

Tags: database

I need to add a post content via database.. I added a `post_title`, `post_description`, categories and tags.. I have tried featured image to set via database but its not working.. Can anyone suggest me to set featured image via database.

In `wp_posts` Table,

```
INSERT INTO `wp_posts`(`post_type`, `guid`, `post_status` , `post_mime_type`) VALUES ('attachment', 'http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/science-2.jpg', 'publish', 'image/jpeg')
```

In wp_postsmeta Table,

```
INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta`( `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (12 , '_thumbnail_id', 20)
```

Its showing like this empty image..

[image]

Suggest me what to do for that....

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **never ever use Plain SQL query to WordPress**, because it's too dangerous. Try [$wpdb class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), if you need to.

BTW, adding posts, post description, assigning featured image, etc. there are wrapper functions designated for these particular tasks, like:

- [`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)
- [`set_post_thumbnail()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail) - for assigning featured images

Always, try to consult Codex or Developer Guide for true direction.

Comment: I read those links.. These are based on Php Coding. But i Need to add featured image in database itself.. Can You say how to add featured image using database query..

Comment: I don't understand your SQL to PHP way. Anyway, your `INSERT INTO 'wp_postmeta'( 'post_id', 'meta_key', 'meta_value') VALUES ($parent_post_id , '_thumbnail_id', $image_id)` should work.

Comment: And in the first query, `post_status` should be `inherit`

Comment: I changed post_status from publish to inherit, but still its looking like that screenshot..